# Finding an isomorphism between these two finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^3 + x + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ and $\beta$ a root of $x^3 + x^2 + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}_2[x]$. Then we know that $$\mathbb{Z}_2(\alpha) \simeq  \frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{(x^3 + x + 1)} \simeq \mathbb{F}_8 \simeq \frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{(x^3 + x^2 + 1)} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2(\beta). $$

I need to find an explicit isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_2(\alpha) \to \mathbb{Z}_2(\beta). $

I was thinking of finding a basis for $\mathbb{Z}_2(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2(\beta)$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

I let $\left\{1, \alpha, \alpha^2\right\}$ and $\left\{1, \beta, \beta^2\right\}$ be these two bases. Now suppose I have a field morphism $$ \phi: \mathbb{Z}_2(\alpha) \to \mathbb{Z}_2(\beta) $$ which maps $1$ to $1$. how can I show that the image of $\alpha$, i.e. $\phi(\alpha)$, completely determines this map?

Comment: What about $x\mapsto x+1$?

Comment: Ok, so I let $\alpha \mapsto 1 + \alpha$. I've proven that $\phi(\alpha)$ is then a root of $(x^3 + x^2 + 1) \in \mathbb{Z}_2(\beta)$. Is there some systematic way to find out the others roots aswell?

Comment: Divide $x^3+x^2+1$ by $x-\phi(\alpha)$, that leaves you with a quadratic in $\Bbb{Z}_2(\alpha)[x]$.

Comment: As for your actual question; because any ring morphism from $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$ is determined by $x$, any ring morphism from its quotient $\Bbb{Z}_2(\alpha)$ is determined by $\alpha$.

Comment: The same question was asked a week ago (no answers, though): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048735/irreducibility-in-mathbbf-2-and-field-extensions#comment4205579_2048735

Comment: Going reciprocal helps such as [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/108717/11619) and a number of earlier examples. Surprisingly I did not find an exact duplicate. May be the duplicate does not have the [tag:finite-field] tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can notice that if $\alpha^3+\alpha+1=0$, then
$$
\alpha^3\left(1+\frac{1}{\alpha^2}+\frac{1}{\alpha^3}\right)=0
$$
and so $\beta=\alpha^{-1}$ is a root of $x^3+x^2+1$. And conversely.

Thus, if you want an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_2(\alpha)\to\mathbb{Z}_2(\beta)$ you just send $\alpha$ to $\beta^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

An important thing to notice  in how we send the base is to notice that
$$\alpha^3+\alpha=1$$
and
$$\beta^3+\beta^2=1$$
and as such we have to have that the image of the former will equal the latter. 
Using binomial theorem we get that
$$(\beta+1)^3=\beta^3+3\beta^2+3\beta+1=\beta^3+\beta^2+\beta+1$$
and then we get that
$$(\beta+1)^3+(\beta+1)=\beta^3+\beta^2=1$$
so we see that $\alpha\mapsto\beta+1$ will sate our requirements. This is important as the multiplication ins both basis is slightly different by the letters and such but fundamentally follow the same pattern. A quick check will show this mapping gives us the entire basis
$$\alpha\mapsto\beta+1$$
$$\alpha^2\mapsto(\beta+1)^2=\beta^2+1$$
$$\alpha^3\mapsto(\beta+1)^3=\beta^3+\beta^2+\beta+1$$
from this we see we can acquire the entire basis of $\Bbb Z_2[\beta]$ through these mappings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do you show that the image of $\alpha$, i.e. $\beta + 1$ is a root of $x^3 + x^2 + 1$? If I plug $\beta + 1$ in that polynomial, I get $\beta^2 + \beta$, using the identity you shown. Why does this equal zero?

Comment: $\beta+1$ is not a zero, it doesn't need to equal any of the zeros of the polynomial. There is no need for it to be that way. All that it needs to do is that it maps elements from one to the other and be a homomorphism and bijection. If it maps a zero to a zero is not a neccesity.